# how to run locally defined function on ssh remote-host?

Tags: bash, ssh, function

I'm using bash, and below is my sample script.
I've defined a function for remote ssh host, that runs another function. but when executed, it doesn't print anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wdir=/var/www/html

function sf {
 echo $wdir
}


function bf {
 ssh remote-host "$(typeset -f sf); sf"
}

bf
```

I tried this typeset command suggested in few of stack's threads..but it seems not working

Comment: It's not about the function, it's about `wdir` being unset on the server side. If `sf` run `echo "$PATH"`, then you would see something, because there is some `PATH` on the server. This is a comment, not an answer, because an answer to "how to run locally defined function on ssh remote-host?" may be "like you just did, the function *itself* did work".

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes but variable is defined, and this is how local variable is called on remote-host, if I recall it right. I mean it should work.

Comment: Kamil said it.  ssh is the shell on the remote host.  Yes, you can specify a command, but those commands must be resident on the remote host and be executed at the remote host.  All parametes passed are interpreted by the remote shell, NOT the local shell.

Comment: You took an effort to copy the local function to the remote side, not the value of the local variable. See what `typeset -f sf` expands to locally, imagine you are the remote shell; what code do you get? The value of the local variable is nowhere in this code.